# Java Sorting Array

Tags: java

I have this code and I do not know why the selection sort is not sorting all the way Does anyone know where to fix the program. The selection sort code I believe is right i just dont know what is wrong. The code is functioning

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class selectionSort
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  int temp;

  int i,j,first;



  System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
  int ammount = scanner.nextInt();
  int[]array = new int[ammount];

  for (i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) 
  {

     System.out.println("Enter the numbers now.");
     array[i] = scanner.nextInt();

  }

  System.out.println("\nThe  array is:");
  for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     System.out.print(array[i] + " ");

  }




  for (i=array.length - 1; i>0;i--)
  {
     first=0;
     for(j=1;j<=1;j++)
     {
        if(array[j]<array[first])
           first = j;

     }

     temp = array[first];

     array[first] = array[i];
     array[i]=temp;

  }


  System.out.println("\nThe sorted array is:");
  for( i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     System.out.print(array[i] + " ");

   }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You appear to have a typo. This line:

```
for(j=1;j<=1;j++)
```

should probably be:

```
for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
```

(The loop termination test should be `j<=i`, not `j<=1`.)